# How to replace strings including `.` (dot) as first character using dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace

Tags: dired, regular-expressions, find-dired, query-replace-regexp

```
(defun my-find-orgfiles ()
  (interactive)
  (find-name-dired "." "*py"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'my-find-orgfiles)
```

Than, `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then I use `Q` to use `query-replace on the marked files`. And enter `.value` to replace with `value`.

---

=> What am I trying to do?
Replace a string that is starting or ending with `.` (dot) such as: `.value` or `value.`.

=> What happens instead?
During replacement Emacs also finds text such as `(value`, `[space]value`, `[value` and so on. In other words, `.value` is matching any character followed by `value`.

=> How can I force `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` (bound to `Q` in Dired buffers) to look for a *literal* **`.`** during string replacement?

Comment: After use of `M-n`, I press `t` and `Q`. Afterwards `Query replace regexp in marked files` pops up and I type `.value` goal is to replace it with `value`. So basically on the selected files I want to replace `.value` with`value`

Comment: Ah, so you use `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then you use `Q` to use query-replace on the marked files. You might want to add that info to the question, for clarity.

Comment: Yes, please. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions and answers should stand on their own. They are what get searched on the site and what get indexed by search engines (e.g. Google). No important info should be kept only in comments, in general. Thx.

Comment: I updated, I hope it is more clear

Comment: Yes. Thanks. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with `find-name-dired`.

This is about `Q` in Dired buffers (including from `find-name-dired`).

`Q` is `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace`. That command treats your first input pattern as a **regexp**.  And `.` in a regexp matches any character except newline.

What you want to use, instead of `.value`, is **`[.]value`**.  That is, you want a pattern that matches only a **`.`** character.

Comment: This also occurs for words ending with `.` right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with words, per se. In a regexp, the character `.` matches any character other than a newline char. So yes, if you're asking about, say, `value.`, then that would match `value?`, `value)`, `value[`, `valueX`, `values`, etc.